# Unsigned IPA in xcode 6

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm wondering is it still possible for xcode 6 users to create unsigned IPAs (for example, without provisioning profiles), to be installed in jailbroken devices?

There are a bunch of ways to do that on xcode 5, Like changing the configuration of the project or trying to archive it (xcode 6 now doesn't allow you to archive at all if you don't have any profile), but none of them worked.

Is it some kind of Apple enforcement, or I'm just missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I have the answer for you! For more assistance try https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a4kelBsxZVs

Step 1:
GoTo /Applications then right click Xcode.app and click "Show Package Contents"

Step 2:
GoTo Contents / Developer / Platforms / iPhoneOS.platform / Developer / SDKs / iPhoneOS7.0.sdk/

and copy the file SDKSettings.plist to desktop

Step 3:
Open the file copied SDKSettings.plist. Under DefaultProperties, dict

find "CODE_ SIGNING_ REQUIRED" and change its value from YES to NO. Save the file

Step 4:
Copy this modified SDKSettings.plist file back to 
    Contents / Developer / Platforms / iPhoneOS.platform / Developer / SDKs / iPhoneOS7.0.sdk/
replacing the orginal file
Do the required AUTHENTICATION AS REQUIRED

Step 5:
Restart Xcode and open your runnable xcode project

Step 6:
In Project Navigator select your project and open Build Settings section of your porject and Select All sub-heading.

Step 7:
Under Code Signing find Code Signing Identity and for both Debug and Release modes set Any iOS SDK to Don't Code Sign.

To make an IPA:

Step 8:
In Xcode, goto Product and click Archive

Step 9:
Step7 will build you project and create an Archive. After the completion of the process, new window Organize - Archive will be opened. In the list of this window you can see your project. Right click project and click Show in Finder which will reveal .xcarchive file

Step 10:
Right click the .xcarchive file and click Show Package Contents and goto Products,  Applications where you will see an app file with the name of your project projectname.app

Step11: 
Open iTunes change view to Apps and drag the app file projectname.app  into the iTunes.

Step12:
Right Click your app, click Show in Finder. There you will have you .ipa file.

Important Notes :
1. In Step 8, if the Archive menu is disabled this is most likely because the a simulator option is currently selected as the run target in the Xcode toolbar. Changing this menu either to a connected device, or the generic iOS Device target option should enable the Archive option in Product menu.

Comment: This is one of the existing way that is working in Xcode 5. The first part of the tutorial no longer works in  Xcode 6 (You select Don't code sign and the build fails); the IPA generating still works if you have a valid provision profile for at least 1 device.

Comment: With XCode 8.2, I couldn't able to drag .app file to iTunes to create ipa file since it is showing an error "could not be added to your itunes library because it is not a valid app". Can you please give some inputs on this issue?

Comment: I just added bundle identifier, then tried the same. Now, I could able to add the .app to iTunes to create .ipa